Eslint does not see the import error, how can I fix it?
I'm sorry for the broken English.
I use quasar using typescript code inside the file .vue (vue 3). I created the interface and imported it import { ICut, ICutMasterItem } from '@/models/cut/cut';, after which if I delete the interface ICut from the file, the project will still assemble and only the IDE will give an error, how to make the project not assemble.
enter image description here
enter image description here
I tried to find the necessary eslint rules and connected different plugins, but I didn't work out any of them

You can use TypeScript's strict mode and enable the noImplicitAny compiler option.
In your 'tsconfig.json', make sure compilerOptions has strict and noImplicitAny set to true:
"compilerOptions": {
  "strict": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true
}

EDIT: I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood your question. If you want to enforce stricter type checking in ESLint, you need to have @typescript-eslint/parser and @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin packages, which you probably already do and add the following configuration in '.eslintrc':
{
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": yourEcmaVersionHere,
    "sourceType": "module"
  }
}

